# How to set output file permissions using matplotlib savefig()?

Tags: python, matplotlib, permissions

How can I specify the *nix read/write permissions for an output file (e.g. PDF) produced by the matplotlib `savefig()` command from within a Python script? i.e. without having to use `chmod` after the file has been produced.

Comment: savefig() does not have capability to change file permissions.  It has to be done afterwards with os.chmod(path, mode) for example os.chmod('fname, 0o400).

Comment: @TrisNefzger You should post that as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`matplotlib.pyplot.savefig()` does not have capability to change file permissions. It has to be done afterwards with `os.chmod(path, mode)` for example `os.chmod(fname, 0o400)`.

Comment: Can you please show me the example? I want to use this on a virtual machine and it is giving same error of 'access denied'.